# Issue with static library in c

Tags: c, ubuntu-14.04, static-libraries

I'm trying to create a static library in `C`. I'm use `gcc version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3)`

My c files is here:

```
add.c //Addition operation perform
sub.c // Subtract operation perform
mul.c // Multiply operation perform
div.c // Division operation perform
```

And I'm trying to crate static library `libabc.a` using following command.

```
ar rcs libabc.a add.c sub.c mul.c div.c
```

And It's successfully created. but when I run executable using `./a.out ./libabc.a`, I got following error.

```
./libabc.a: error adding symbols: Archive has no index; run ranlib to add one
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What I doing wrong? please help me.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

Use object files(`.o`) instead of source file(`.c`). Like,

```
ar rcs libabc.a sum.o mul.o add.o div.o
```

Using `-c` option , create `.o` file.

```
cc -c -fpic add.c sub.c mul.c div.c
```

To link purely statically library, use `-static`, Like

```
cc -static yourprgram.c  libabc.a
```

And run executable `./a.out`. It successfully work.